# Python: Pause some activities but allow other parts of the code to continue

Tags: python-3.x, nextion

I have a Python 3 script running on a Raspberry Pi (Buster) which writes some instrument data to my Nextion Display using the serial/UART interface.  I have, for now, setup my code to sleep for 5 minutes after the current data are displayed.  This working.

The Nextion Display is touch sensitive so that if I touch it, it will send a serial data string which can be read via my script and will tell me where on the screen it was touched.

Now, I would like to modify my code such that it will react to the touch-screen even during the sleep period.  I could put the program into a tight loop instead of using time.sleep(300) and check the elapsed time and read the serial port during each loop.  This sounds to me like I would be overworking the Pi and wasting CPU cycles.  Is there a better way to pause certain sections of code while allowing other to continue?

Comment: You're not saving CPU cycles by using sleep, so you might as well just poll shorter but more frequently.

Comment: Thank you for you reply.  I guess my question dates me a bit, as I recall issues when accidental tight-loops got me in trouble at the university many years ago.  I guess with these little stand-alone computers, that is less of an issue.  Again thanks for your comments.